# Does there exist a canonical form for normal matrices which extends the following embedding?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-theory, multiset

Given an unordered pair of complex numbers $\{w,z\}$, we can associate to it the complex matrix
$$\frac 1 2\left[\begin{matrix}w + z + \frac{\left(w - z\right)^{2} + \left|{w - z}\right|^{2}}{2 \left|{w - z}\right|} & \frac{i \left(w - z\right)^{2} - i \left|{w - z}\right|^{2}}{2 \left|{w - z}\right|}\\\frac{i \left(w - z\right)^{2} - i \left|{w - z}\right|^{2}}{2 \left|{w - z}\right|} & w + z + \frac{- \left(w - z\right)^{2} - \left|{w - z}\right|^{2}}{2 \left|{w - z}\right|}\end{matrix}\right]
.$$
Call the mapping $f(\{w,z\})$. Make the following observations:

- The mapping has a limit at $\{z,z\}$. So the function has no essential singularities, and can therefore be continuously extended to all unordered pairs of complex numbers.
- $f(\{w,z\})$ is a normal matrix.
- The mapping $f$ is continuous and has a continuous inverse over its image. It is therefore an embedding of unordered pairs into the normal matrices.
- The eigenvalues of $f(\{w,z\})$ are $w$ and $z$.

Another vague observation can be made, which is that multiset operations on $\{w,z\}$ translate into matrix operations on $f(\{w,z\})$. Namely:

- The sum of the elements of the multiset is the trace of the matrix.
- The product of the elements of the multiset is the determinant of the matrix.
- The real part of the multiset is the Hermitian part of the matrix (and similarly for the imaginary part and magnitude).
- If $g: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is an analytic function, then $f(\{g(w), g(z)\}) = g(f(\{w,z\}))$.

This particular embedding of multisets into complex matrices differs from another one I know by enabling one to take the real and imaginary parts, and magnitudes, of the elements of the multiset.

This leads me to conjecture the following:

- The above can be generalised to a canonical form for all normal matrices under unitary similarity.
- The mapping from a normal matrix to its canonical form can be made continuous.

Is this true? Linear algebra is well-developed enough that I imagine some work has been done on this.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think that the answer to my conjecture (that such a continuous mapping is possible) is "no". The reason being that I think it would enable one to construct a continuous function that takes the cube root of a complex number (which is impossible) through the following sequence of operations: Take a complex number $z$, construct a cubic polynomial with only real roots with the real part of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ as a root, map it continuously to its multiset of roots, map this multiset to a canonical matrix representative, observe that the result is Hermitian, find the eigenvalues.

Comment: You repeatedly wrote `\left(w-z\right)` where `(w-z)` would have the same effect, and `\left|{w-z}\right|` where `\left|w-z\right\` would have the same effect. Usually `\left` and `\right` have no effect except when they make the parentheses grow to larger sizes to enclose larger things, as in $\left(\dfrac a b\right)$ as opposed to $(\dfrac a b).$ (But with absolute-value signs, they sometimes affact horizontal spacing as well.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's output from Sympy, which I've edited to look decent when rendered in latex.